# Lightweight Javascript slider (jQuery and Raphael libraries in use)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, raphael

Is there a solid minimalist Javascript slider that would be idealf or use in this situation (only two sliders are used on the entire application):

[image]

I'm really not a fan of jQuery UI - it's really heavy and I don't like the skinning methods.

I'm looking for something IE7+ supported.

Comment: [YUI 2](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/slider/) has one. See also [this list](http://www.noupe.com/javascript/30-javascriptajax-techniques-for-sliders-scrollers-and-scrollbars.html). "javascript slider control" is what you want to Google for.

Answer (score 3):

Well you have it for free in `html5`, not exactly supported on every browser but...

```
 <input type="range" value="0" max="50" min="0" />
```